# Delete multiple lines by specifying their line numbers in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-manipulation

I have a text file that has 255 lines and I want to delete/remove specific non-consecutive lines (lines 2, 4, 56, and 180 for example) regardless of their contents. I cannot use regular expression replace as I do not want to touch the other lines. I was thinking of a feature similar to `Go To` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) wherein I specify the lines and delete those lines, or perhaps a feature like *Replace in lines* so that I can replace the specific lines with nothing. Is there a way to do this in Notepad++?

Comment: In notepad++, there is a way to bookmark lines with a search, and then delete those bookmarked lines. No regex necessary. If a search is not needed, the you can bookmark the lines to remove with `Ctrl+F2`, and then use menu `Search => Bookmark => Remove Bookmarked Lines`.

Answer (score 1):

You metionded to delete/remove **specific** non-consecutive lines regardless of their contents.

For these special lines in my opinion a regular expression or function makes sense only when you need to repeat this very often.

From comments above bookmarking by manually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in combination is my recommendation too.

So you can quickly mark some lines by repeating the key sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, **linenumber**, <kbd>Enter</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> with the existing functionality.

Of course, for multiple use with the same lines, a macro can be recorded and executed.

As a further option, you should nevertheless use the functions on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> tab (e.g. Regular expression, Bookmark line, ...) for your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to directly input the line numbers themselves like in Go To, instead of having to bookmark the lines separately, which can be very tedious if you have many specific lines that you want to delete?

Comment: @JAT86 - see my edit.